# Clarification on twinview vs dualview tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I was tagging a multimonitor question and initially chose dualview, although it does not exist currently I have used/seen this often.

I did a little searching and came across this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=221174) so decided twinview would be more appropriate however it seems to be an Nvidia only term.

What are the thoughts on this?

I think it is important as searching for multi-monitor issues can be tricky.

If twinview is to be specific for nvidia what tag should non-nvidia users with the same monitor setup use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual tag for questions regarding multiple monitors is [multiple-monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors).

I would strongly advise you against using [dualview](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dualview) (as it has not been used by anyone else).

If your question is related to Nvidia [twinview](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/twinview) then it might be a good idea to use that tag instead or as well as [multiple-monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors).

You can also tag your graphics card manufacturer: [nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/nvidia), [ati](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ati), [amd-graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amd-graphics) or [intel-graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/intel-graphics).

Comment: Yes I would use multiple-monitors tag as well however dualview/twinview are specific versions of this. I've added a  revision to the question.

Comment: @Cas I think "dual view" is just another generic name, such as "multihead", "dualmonitor", "multiple-monitors", etc